# DateFromString returns wrong value

Tags: xcode, macos, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I'm using NSDateFormatter  and datefromString  is a whole year off

```
NSString *date    = [[command substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(pos.location + 3, command.length - pos.location - 9)] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

NSLog(@"  date        [%@]   " , date       ); 
NSLog(@"  lastAccess  [%@]   " , lastAccess );
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init]; 
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"]; 
[dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]]; 
NSDate *filedate = [dateFormat dateFromString:date];

NSLog(@"1     %@   %f  " , filedate    , [filedate   timeIntervalSince1970]); 
NSLog(@"2     %@   %f  " , lastAccess  , [lastAccess timeIntervalSince1970]); 
NSLog(@"3     %@   " , date);
```

produces the following output

```
  date        [2012-11-18 19:00:23 +0000]   
  lastAccess  [2012-11-18 19:00:21 +0000]   
  1     2011-11-18 19:00:23 +0000   1321642823.000000  
  2     2012-11-18 19:00:21 +0000   1353265221.929860  
  3     2012-11-18 19:00:23 +0000
```

Date  has 2012  which is confirm again with 3)

But check out  1)  it has 2011
Yet 1) filedate   datefromstring  of date

Any ideas ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I tried your code. Seems to working fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use lower case letters for the year.

your dateformat should be `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z`.

according to the [unicode date format guide](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-19.html#Date_Format_Patterns)

- yyyy means Year
- YYYY means Year in "Week of Year" based calendars.

I am not sure why this yields different results, but you should almost always use the lowercase variant.